# JavaFX Circle Linear Gradient Fill by Percentage

Tags: java, javafx, linear-gradients

I just want to make an indicator for customer how much he/she used his/hers data/sms/voice using two circles and linear-gradient, but some values are not behaving as wanted. How can I make them behave same as in the image on the left?

[image]

This is the code I am using to create the gradient:

```
private void createCircleBar(int x, int y, int usedAmount, int remainingAmount) {
    int totalAmount = usedAmount + remainingAmount;
    int percentage = 100*usedAmount/totalAmount;
    Circle outerCircle = new Circle(x,y,50);
    LinearGradient g = LinearGradient.valueOf("from 0.0% 100.0% to 0.0% 0.0% rgb(14,170,0) 0.0%, rgb(14,170,0) "+(100-percentage)+"%, rgb(148,0,0) "+percentage+"%,rgb(148,0,0) 100.0%");
    outerCircle.setFill(g);
    anchor.getChildren().add(outerCircle);
    Circle innerCircle = new Circle(x,y,39);
    innerCircle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
    anchor.getChildren().add(innerCircle);
}
```

Comment: *"Some values are not behaving as wanted"*. Can you be more specific? Which values? How are they behaving and how do you want them to behave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking to do is to have the red color `rgb(148,0,0)` from the top, extending down an amount determined by `percentage`, followed by the green color `rgb(14, 170, 0)` from that point to the bottom, with no actual color gradient in between the two colors.

A `LinearGradient` will interpolate the colors between any "color stops" you specify. So to create a hard change between two colors, you need two color stops at the same position, with one color changing to the other.

The following gives you what I think you are looking for:

```
LinearGradient g = LinearGradient.valueOf(
    "from 0.0% 0.0% to 0.0% 100.0% "+    // from top to bottom
    "rgb(148, 0, 0) 0%, "+               // red at the top
    "rgb(148, 0, 0) "+percentage+"%, "+  // red at percentage
    "rgb(14, 147, 0) "+percentage+"%, "+ // green at percentage
    "rgb(14, 147, 0) 100%"               // green at the bottom
);
```

Note you can literally use `"from top to bottom "` instead of `"from 0% 0% to 0% 100% "`.